# Difference in datetime => timestamp only in some cases?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

While trying to compare values between Python and MySQL, I came across a very odd bug.

I have a "created" column in the database (of type "datetime"), and I have for instance these two values:

```
"2018-03-15 10:11:47"
"2018-10-28 02:06:08"
```

When converted to Timestamp using UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created), I get the following:

```
1521105107
1540688768
```

Now, if I recreate these dates in Python, and get the timestamp (Python3), I get the following:

For the first date:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=3, day=15, hour=10, minute=11, second=47)
print(int(dt.timestamp()))
$> 1521105107 # Same as the database
```

For the second date:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=10, day=28, hour=2, minute=6, second=8)
print(int(dt.timestamp()))
$> 1540685168 # Different!
```

Why? What is happening?

If I had any delta on the database or Python because of the timestamp, it would be for every line, not a few.

I'm suspecting the database is keeping track of some timezone for the `created` column, but not displayed, but I'm stuck there ...

Comment: I suspect its a difference in timezones that's causing your problem. Your database and your local machine (or where you are running python on) are probably using different default timezones and adjusting accordingly when you try to convert it. Probably a good idea to see which one is using which timezone.

Comment: The function UNIX_TIMESTAMP essentially will take your DATETIME value interpreted in the current time zone and convert it to UTC (actually the number of seconds elapsed since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC). The fact that one of the converted datetimes compares equal with your Python value (was this computed on the same box?) but the other is off by one hour is interesting. It does suggest that different time zones are in effect for the two environments but the difference might just be that one is using daylight savings time and the other isn't. Just a guess, but check it out.

Comment: My previous comment hinted but did not make explicit the fact the DATETIME columns do *not* have any time zone information stored within. The MySql server's session has the notion of a default current timezone that is in effect and it is that value, which you can change with `set session time_zone='time zone specification';`, that is used to provide the "missing" time zone information when calling UNIX_TIMESTAMP. Try: `SELECT IF(@@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone);`

Comment: DATETIME represents the local time, while TIMESTAMP is time zone aware.

Comment: Hi @RonaldAaronson and thank you for your post. The DST might be the solution here! When putting the two different timestamps on https://www.epochconverter.com/, it clearly shows the same hour, but the first with "2:06:08 AM GMT+01:00" and the second with ... "2:06:08 AM GMT+02:00 DST". The issue is, I can't wrap my head around how EpochConverter know when to use DST or not. (Of course, I used the same browser, even the same page when testing, and din't changed a thing in  between). Do you have an idea?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson I think that in the Python case, the UTC date resolves to October 28, which changed Summertime to Wintertime and such added/removed an hour. But the problem is, how can I have common data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that when dealing with a DATETIME column that the timezone being used by your MySql server is the same as the one being used by your Python environment, specifically when you are initializing that column with a value produced from a function call such as NOW() or, for example, when you are converting that column with a call to UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

So, the first thing I do when I connect is to issue a command such as `'set time_zone = 'America/New_York';` (but only because *I* LOVE New York; *you* might LOVE some other place) and then I don't need to worry if my server is in Utah or in New York nor do I need to know when daylight savings time is in effect. If you find that a timezone such as 'America/New_York' is unavailable on your server, then you should look at [Time zone description tables](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html). Secondly, you should install Python package [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/). You will then have access to many additional timezones. **And use an explicit timezone when constructing a `datetime.datetime` object!** For all I know, my ISP's Python environment may not have the same exact timezone setting as its MySql server and neither is what I would want to use anyway. Hopefully, if you follow these guidelines, these discrepancies should disappear. if not, I'll give your money back.

Comment: Setting the timezone to UTC at MySQL level (with `SET time_zone="+00:00"`) and at Python level (with `dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None).timestamp()`) made it work.